# D3.js abort transition and prevent end event

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've got a fancy little D3 transition that fires on mouseover of a particular svg element. I want to fire off a function when the transition completes. No problem. Per the documentation, I need only listen for the "end" event on the transition. Here's where I'm having trouble: If the user mouses OUT of the triggering item before the transition completes, I want to abort the transition and NOT fire my function. Every mechanism that I've found by which I can prematurely end the transition still dispatches the end event.

I've tried transition().duration(0), which I understand would overwrite my transition with a new 0-duration one, but the end event still fires. I can't figure out how I would interrupt and destroy a transition without firing the end event. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should chain your transitions instead of waiting for the end event and then firing your transition.  When a transition is stopped, the entire chain stops.  This is intended so newer animations can execute.

Here is an example of chaining:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997

Just remove the `.each("end", repeat);` and watch what happens

Hope this helps.